# JQuery - Parents

Tags: jquery, parent

I want to display either "OPEN" or "CLOSED", depending on the conditional, in the parent, but I don't know how to do this. This code makes two `<h2>` headings work as a drop down list. I want the function to pass the parameters, and if it does not equal 1, I want to display OPEN in the `<span>` of the `<h2>`.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = null;
    var b = null;
    var c = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".toggle_container").hide();
        $("h2.trigger").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    function divide(a, b) {
        (a / b != c) ?
      // Where help is needed
      //  $(this).parent(".status").text("OPEN").css("color", "green") :
      //  $("team").parent(".status").text("CLOSED").css("color","red");
        document.write(a + " / " + b);
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <body>
    <div class="tournaments">
    <h2 class="trigger">Tournament 1<span class="status"></span></h2>
        <div class="toggle_container">
            <div class="block">
                <h3>Details</h3>
                <p>Deadline: DATE</p>
                <p>Teams: <span class="team"><script type="text/javascript">divide(3, 7)</script></span>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <h2 class="trigger">Tournament 2 <span class="status"></span></h2>
        <div class="toggle_container">
            <div class="block">
                <h3>Details</h3>
                <p>Deadline: DATE</p>
                <p>Teams: <span class="team"><script type="text/javascript">divide(3,7)</script></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a JavaScript function in HTML the way you're doing, that function has no awareness of what HTML element contains it. One way to bypass that problem (my favorite way) is to put those variables in `data-` attributes for the DOM element, and use jQuery to extract and operate on them using `.data()`.

Your second problem is that the `h2` tag isn't a parent (container) of the `span.team` element. A little more DOM traversal is necessary to get to the one from the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fzwBM/

new HTML:

```
<div class="tournaments">
    <h2 class="trigger">Tournament 1<span class="status"></span></h2>
    <div class="toggle_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>Details</h3>
            <p>Deadline: DATE</p>
            <p>Teams: <span class="team" data-a="3" data-b="7"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="trigger">Tournament 2 <span class="status"></span></h2>
    <div class="toggle_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h3>Details</h3>
            <p>Deadline: DATE</p>
            <p>Teams: <span class="team" data-a="3" data-b="7"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

new JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle_container").hide();
    $("h2.trigger").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $('span.team').each(function() {
        var a = $(this).data('a');
        var b = $(this).data('b');
        var $status = $(this).closest('.toggle_container').prev('.trigger').find('.status');
console.log($status.length);
        if (a != b) {   // if a/b!=1, then a!=b
            $status.text("OPEN").css("color", "green");
        } else {
            $status.text("CLOSED").css("color", "red");
        }
        $(this).text(a + " / " + b);
    });
});
```

Comment: So, when you use `.closest` it finds the nearest "toggle_"container" from where you are currently in the DOM tree. Once you get to `.prev()`, I get lost. Is previous the element before the current one? Why couldn't you use `.closest('.trigger')`?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pass in the ID of the span you would like to manipulate:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp99T/3/